# Called .save on a ruby object is only passing nil for all strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am having trouble with some beginner level issues in Ruby, specifically with just saving an object into the database. Here is the code

```
def add_user     
  firstName = params[:name];     
  email = params[:email];     
  user = User.new(:name=>'test', :email=>email)    
  puts "user name" + user.name     
  if user.save       
    puts "User saved"    
  end     
end
```

Unfortunately, this is what it generates after the `save`:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at")
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 17:24:52 UTC +00:00], ["email", nil], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 17:24:52 UTC +00:00]]
```

Everything gets passed as `nil`, despite me actually hardcoding `'test'` into the name field. Also the `puts "user.name" + user.name` does print out the correct name. The datamodels do match up for the `User` object.

```
Schema Information
Table name: users

  id         :integer         # not null, primary key
  name       :string(255)
  email      :string(255)
  created_at :datetime
  updated_at :datetime
```

So I am not really sure what is going on. I've tried to see if im supposed to be using the instance variables or not and i seem to keep getting the same result. This also appears to be following all the steps ive read in any books or tutorials. Is there something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `User` model look like?

Comment: What happens if you change `user = User.new(:name=>'test', :email=>email)` to `user = User.create(:name=>'test', :email=>email)` and remove the save?

Comment: @James class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name,:email
end
Sorry for the formatting. New here.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `attr_accessor` in your model when you probably meant to use `attr_accessible`. This is the second question with this mistake and I'm wondering where people are getting `attr_accessor` from. Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: Thanks! this was the issue. In regards to your question, im reading Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial - Addison Wesley, page 152 under section 4.4.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot @James, Helped me too..Was struggling with similar ... at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186446/saving-a-record-but-not-saving#comment19663660_14186446