# Saving a record.. but not saving... :(

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this static method for a model, which is creating multiple records.  This method is called when saving the parent, the data for creating appropriate n child records is passed to this method (new_record) which then iterates through the array passed to it, and creates the child records.

Job has many Job Activities. This method new_record belongs to job_activities model and is invoked in job_controller, when saving job record. Basically trying to implement two models in a single form.  Job "has_many" job_activities, and Job_activites "belongs_to" a job.

Here's what I have put together so far -

```
       def self.new_record(sk_job_id, activities_list)
        activities_list.each do | act |
          puts "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA creating a new record for "+act.inspect+" and " + sk_job_id.to_s
            ja = JobActivity.new
            puts "Job ID SK = "+sk_job_id.to_s
            puts "act = "+act
            puts "Record before assignment "+ ja.inspect
            ja.job_id_sk = sk_job_id
            ja.job_activity = act
            ja.created_by  = "raghav"
            ja.updated_by  = "raghav"
            puts "Record after assignment "+ ja.inspect            
            ja.save!
            puts "record after saving "+ ja.inspect
        end
      end
```

Weird thing happening is, that the before and after assignment state of the object ja, reflects the assignment of "created_by" but not of job_id_sk and job_activity...

And, as suggested, I implemented the save! but that didnt raise any exceptions.. its still quite silently behaving what its doing... :(

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA creating a new record for "ACT1" and 40
Job ID SK = 40
act = ACT1
Record before assignment #<JobActivity id: nil, job_id_sk: nil, job_activity: nil, created_by: nil, updated_by: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Record after assignment #<JobActivity id: nil, job_id_sk: nil, job_activity: nil, created_by: "raghav", updated_by: "raghav", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

record after saving #<JobActivity id: 13, job_id_sk: nil, job_activity: nil, created_by: "raghav", updated_by: "raghav", created_at: "2013-01-08 02:22:30", updated_at: "2013-01-08 02:22:30">
```

However, when I go and check the mysql table where the data should have been saved, I see that only NULL values have been passed in...

```
mysql> select job_id_sk, job_activity from job_activities;
+-----------+--------------+
| job_id_sk | job_activity |
+-----------+--------------+
|      NULL | NULL         |
|      NULL | NULL         |
|      NULL | NULL         |
|      NULL | NULL         |
|      NULL | NULL         |
+-----------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I missing something somewhere  ?

Comment: Try `ja.save!` and you will find where is your problem.

Comment: You might want to make your `job_id_sk` and `job_activity` columns NOT NULL to provide an extra layer of protect. I'd even say that you should make everything NOT NULL (even though the default is to allow NULLs) unless you have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, and the solution...

I was using attr_accessor for the model, whereas I should have been using attr_accessible...

Response from James on this question helped me..

[Called .save on a ruby object is only passing nil for all strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672033/called-save-on-a-ruby-object-is-only-passing-nil-for-all-strings)

Answer (score 0):

`model#save` returns true or false, but `model#save!` (note the `!` at the end of the method name) will raise an exception instead of returning false.

Chances are that the model is failing a validation or was otherwise set up incorrectly.  Using `save!` will immediately and obviously fail, telling you what's actually wrong.

Comment: did that, its going through just fine. No exceptions raised.